# Omnipotent Pork Sword or Katana

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

In Dungeons of Dredmor, I am havign a hard time to pick between these two.

Katana adds 10 slashing, 5 piercing, and 5 enemy dodge reduction.

Omnipotent adds 2 slashing, 2 piercing, 10 necromantic, 10 hp, and 2 hp regen bonus.

On paper, it seems like Omnipotent is better hands down(26 total stats, with the 10 necromantic bypassing armor vs 10 slashing), but why does it have a HUGE difference in stars? Katana is a level 10 Sword class weapon vs the level 4 sword class of Omnipotent Pork Sword.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your Omnipotent Pork Sword has extra enchantments on it?  The [Dredmor Wiki](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Omnipotent_Pork_Sword) says that this sword comes with +2 slashing, +2 piercing, and +10 HP.  The other stats aren't listed there.

The "quality" stars are set by the type of weapon, and don't change if it's been enchanted, so that might explain why it is quite a bit better than a Katana.

On top of the fact that additional enchantments aren't a factor in quality stars,  after looking at the [sword-class weapon list](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Swords), it doesn't look like you can really compare artifacts to "standard" weapons by their quality stars alone.

In general, it seems like the quality star system is kind of bogus.  You'll need to just take a look at the stats on your items to decide which is better.

Comment: hmm didn't realize that. I knew something was 'wrong' with that. Yes it does seem the sword was enchanted although it didn't change it's name. I actually just picked it up somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Since it has massive necromantic damage built-in, I guess the pork sword comes from a Chest of Evil or a similar source. Note artifacts will not change their name upon enchantment.